# Apex Failed Test Run: Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: apex, code-coverage, failing-tests, method, apextestrunresult

I have a class with the function:

```
public static void updateTargetAmount(Id targetId, String customFieldApiName){...}
```

In my Testclass i handover the 2 parameters:

```
 TargetHelper.updateTargetAmount(target.Id, 'Amount')
```

Now the Test Run always show the error:

*Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void updateTargetAmount(Id) from the type TargetHelper.*
I think the parameters were passed incorrectly. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: If you're doing this from an IDE, like VSCode or Illuminated Cloud, try deploying both classes to the org again; a previous deploy may have failed so your local code is different to that on the org.

Comment: BTW, note that your method really should take a list of IDs so it can still be used in bulkified contexts.

Comment: I wrote in the developer console @Phil W

Comment: @Benjamin, Can you confirm what is 'Target' in your test class

Comment: Looking at the error, you may have another class that gets (in)directly referenced by your unit test that is calling the method using a previous version of the method that only took an ID.

Comment: Seeing more of the context surrounding this code and the actual call being made will be helpful. As Phil W noted, the error says that you're _trying to call this method only passing an Id_. There's _something_ going on here, but we don't have enough information to say what that something might be.